# Instantiate a Generic class via Reflection

Tags: c#, .net

I want to instantiate a class via reflection as follows:

```
public class TestConsume<T> : BaseExecutor<T>
{
   public overide SomeMethod(T input)
   {
   }
}
```

Where the BaseClass is:

```
public abstract class BaseExecutor<T> : IExecutor<T>
{
    public T Execute(T input)
    {
    }
}
```

And the interface is:

```
public interface IExecutor<T>
{
    void Execute(T input);
}
```

I've tried numerous ways to get the type of 'TestConsume' but it pretty much always return null.  Any idea how to go about doing this?

the main way I've tried to get the type is:

```
Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Test.TestConsume");
```

I've also used Type.GetType() etc and I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `Assembly.GetType` to work, you need to use the CLR name, which includes the generic *arity* - the number of type parameters it has:

```
Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Test.TestConsume`1");
```

That's assuming you need to do it using a string representation at all. If not, you can just use:

```
Type type = typeof(Test.TestConsume<>);
```

You'll then need to create the appropriate constructed type using `Type.MakeGenericType`:

```
Type constructed = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(string)); // Or whatever
```

Comment: Does that arity have to be `1`? I  can see only one type parameter. Or.. am missing something?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Sorry, just a typo. Fixed.

Comment: yea, I think I do need to use the string representation because I don't know that I am going to be creating Test.TestConsume or maybe some other class called Test.TestConsumeB that also inherits from BaseExecutor

Comment: When jon makes a typo, It makes me feel my understanding was wrong :) Good to know it is a typo..